# Blocked from scraping a website with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, user-agent

I'm still trying to scrape search results from this kind of [URL](http://so.news.cn/getNews?keyword=%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD&curPage=2&sortField=0&searchFields=0&lang=cn), which is the search results for a Chinese online newspaper. Scrapy works for a few requests, and then I get the following terminal output.

> 2019-12-19 11:56:19 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <461 http://so.news.cn/getNews?keyword=%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD&curPage=55&sortField=0&searchFields=0&lang=cn>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

It seems to work better if I add a delay, but then it is very slow. Is this because I am being blocked by the site - and is there anything I can do about it? I don't currently have any special User-Agent defined in settings.py. I have tried using **scrapy-UserAgent** to rotate User-Agent, but it doesn't seem to be working. Would a VPN help?

Thanks

Comment: In what interval are you fetching the results? Probabaly you are doing it too fast and get blocked by the server, i Think a UserAgent doesnt help with that.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the reply. I've tried it with both the default Scrapy settings, and then a download delay = 10. It does work better with the delay, but then the scaper runs a lot more slowly because I guess there's a 10 second delay between each request? Any suggestions as to how to keep it going faster, but avoid the issue?

Comment: You should rotate your IP address using proxy servers. One option for proxies would be https://gimmeproxy.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different solutions to test :

- Random pause between each requests
- Make good use of sessions:

  1) Keep the same session for an amount of request (30 to 60)

  2) Clear your cookies after 30 to 60 request and change the user agent.
    Use this simple python framework: https://pypi.org/project/shadow-useragent/

  3) If that still does not work: rotate your IP over time (every 30 to 60 requests for instance) thanks to a proxy provider, rotate your user-agent, clear your cookies at the same time.

You should now look random for most of the websites. If you see any more bot mitigation (recaptchas) or specialized anti-scraping services, this could get trickier.

Comment: Thanks - very comprehensive suggestions. I've enable the autothrottle in Scrapy, which I think does a random pause between requests. Could you tell me how I incorporate shadow-user agent into the scrapy code? Should I put the code in the settings.py file?

Comment: @nolczak you can find an example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400307/scrapy-correct-way-to-change-user-agent-in-request

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was already said, I'd add that the right proxy service provider is crucial here.

Not only you have to rotate proxies really often, but their success rates have to be high as well, so in your case I'd go with residential IPs, which closely resemble real users.

Not to promote any, but you should look in to those, such as Luminati, Oxylabs, Geosurf etc.

[More information about it here](https://proxyway.com/best-residential-proxies)

Comment: Thanks! I will look into proxy rotation. I also found that with a big delay between requests it works okay