# How to change proxy/user-agent and other settings during scrapy working?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

How to change scrapy settings during spider is working? For example, I need to change proxy after it does 100 requests.

Comment: Your question needs more detail. Please provide an attempt at doing this yourself, and what happened when you tried specifically.

Comment: @AaronS, I have not tried yet but is it possible to change some parameters from settings.py after scraper after an unsuccessful request to the webpage (it got banned, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the proxy for the spider to use per request using:

```
request.meta['proxy'] = 'https://<PROXY_IP_OR_URL>:<PROXY_PORT>'
```

Scrapinghub has info on this that can be found here: https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000219743-using-a-custom-proxy-in-a-scrapy-spider

You can also change the `user-agent` of each request:

```
request.headers['User-Agent'] = 'random-agent'
```

You could try out something similar to the answer here: [Scrapy - Correct way to change User Agent in Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400307/scrapy-correct-way-to-change-user-agent-in-request)