# Web Scraping for Google Image Download for a number of minimum 2K images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-image-search

I am trying with a python script to extract 2000 images from Google, but I am able to download only 80 images. Can anyone help me with the below code on how to modify to get that 2K numbers?

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Google_Image = 'https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1873&bih=990&'

u_agnt = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

Image_Folder = 'Images_1'

def main():
    if not os.path.exists(Image_Folder):
        os.mkdir(Image_Folder)
    download_images()

def download_images():
    data = input('Enter your search keyword: ')
    num_images = int(input('Enter the number of images you want: '))
    
    print('Searching Images....')
    
    search_url = Google_Image + 'q=' + data #'q=' because its a query
    
    # request url, without u_agnt the permission gets denied
    response = requests.get(search_url, headers=u_agnt)
    html = response.text #To get actual result i.e. to read the html data in text mode
    
    # find all img where class='rg_i Q4LuWd'
    b_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') #html.parser is used to parse/extract features from HTML files
    results = b_soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'rg_i Q4LuWd'})
    
    #extract the links of requested number of images with 'data-src' attribute and appended those links to a list 'imagelinks'
    #allow to continue the loop in case query fails for non-data-src attributes
    count = 0
    imagelinks= []
    for res in results:
        try:
            link = res['data-src']
            imagelinks.append(link)
            count = count + 1
            if (count >= num_images):
                break
            
        except KeyError:
            continue
    
    print(f'Found {len(imagelinks)} images')
    print('Start downloading...')

    for i, imagelink in enumerate(imagelinks):
        # open each image link and save the file
        response = requests.get(imagelink)
        
        imagename = Image_Folder + '/' + data + str(i+1) + '.jpg'
        with open(imagename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)

    print('Download Completed!')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please, let me know how I can resolve this and why this limit is happening while downloading the images from Google. Can I need to use something like proxycrawl, if yes how I can use this?

Comment: There is a Python Library to do this: https://pypi.org/project/google_images_download/

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu, thank you for the information. But unable to download, show this message: " Unfortunately all 6 could not be downloaded because some images were not downloadable. 0 is all we got for this search filter! " Codes are: from google_images_download import google_images_download
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

arguments = {"keywords": "dog", "limit":6, "format":"jpg", "print_urls": True}
paths = response.download(arguments)